# Can we run 2 EC2 instances on port 80 (httpd), both using same security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I have created 2 EC2 instances both using the same security group. Now I installed Apache on both the instances. Now when I echo "hello world" I am not able to do that on both the instances, please help I am just a beginner in AWS?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance(s) in a subnet that has route in its associated route table to an internet gateway that is attached to the VPC hosting the EC2 instance(s)?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to do that"?  What are you doing to connect to each instance? What is the configuration of the security group? Please Edit your question to add more details.